# issue with capturing packets from a specific eth interface on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, sockets, packet-sniffers

I have a problem when trying to capture all packets from one specified ethernet interface. I open a AF_PACKET socket, and set the  specified interface on promisc mode. It does capture the packets from the specified interface. However, it also picks up packets from other ethernet interfaces, for example, eth0.

I also tried to see if I can filter out the eth0 interface by calling the  setsockopt with PACKET_DROP_MEMBERSHIP, but it does not work. It still captures packets from eth0.

```
// The following code opens socket and set the specified intf to PACKET_MR_PROMISC
// However, it also picks up packets from all other interfaces, for example, eth0

int fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));

int interface_number = if_nametoindex(interface_name.c_str());
if (interface_number == -1) {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "Can't get interface number for %s.\n", interface_name.c_str());
    return -1;
}
per_socket_data->ifindex = interface_number;
syslog(LOG_INFO, "intf %s, ifindex %d. \n", interface_name.c_str(), interface_number);

// Switch to PROMISC mode
struct packet_mreq sock_params;
memset(&sock_params, 0, sizeof(sock_params));
sock_params.mr_type = PACKET_MR_PROMISC;
sock_params.mr_ifindex = interface_number;
   
int set_promisc = setsockopt(fd, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (void *)&sock_params, sizeof(sock_params));


// The following code tries to prevent capturing packets from eth0. However, this does not work.
int eth0_interface_number = if_nametoindex(eth0.c_str());
if (eth0_interface_number == -1) {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "Can't get interface number for %s.\n", eth0.c_str());
    return -1;
}
syslog(LOG_INFO, "intf %s, ifindex %d. \n", eth0.c_str(), eth0_interface_number);

memset(&sock_params, 0, sizeof(sock_params));
sock_params.mr_ifindex = eth0_interface_number;

int exclude_eth0 = setsockopt(fd, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_DROP_MEMBERSHIP, (void *)&sock_params, sizeof(sock_params));
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tried SO_BINDTODEVICE socket option?

```
struct ifreq ifr;

memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "%s", interface_name.c_str());

setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &ifr, sizeof(ifr));
```

More information about it in man page of socket(7).

Comment: I tried this SO_BINDTODEVICE socket option, but it does not work.